# How to make TabBar without Icons?

Tags: react-native, expo, tabbar

I made the tabBar as below.

[image]

I am using react-native with expo.
But I want to remove icons from tabBar as it having only texts.
my tabBar code looks like below.
How can I remove icons from tabBar?

```js
<Tabs.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      tabBarActiveTintColor: `${colors.vivid}`,
      tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: `${colors.light}`,
      tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "white",
          height: 60,
      },
      tabBarLabelStyle: {
          fontFamily: "Katuri",
          fontSize: 18,
      },
  }}
>
    <Tabs.Screen
      name="사진"
      options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name={"camera"} color={color} size={18} />
          ),
      }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return  `null` for `tabBarIcon` in `options` props.

```js
<Tabs.Screen 
  name="사진" 
  options={{ tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => null }}
```

Comment: Check working example here - https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/getting-started-%7C-react-navigation

Comment: then it shows me blank rectangular.

Comment: can you reproduce your code on Expo Snack as above example

Comment: it works with above example: https://ibb.co/2Y1BhL7. 
But my code still has the blank rectangular: https://ibb.co/FH7jPTL.
The code is same as removing `tabBarIcon` but what is the difference?

Comment: try to return null for icon

`
 <Tabs.Screen
    name="사진"
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => null
    }}`

Comment: I update answer with working solution, you can approve it for future developers who face same issue